# HTML5 canvas hit testing with isPointInPath()

Tags: html, canvas

For the purposes of hit testing with HTML5 canvas I'm thinking of this:

1) coords of a shape (eg a rect) are stored - x,y,w,h
2) When the mouse is moved or clicked the rect is drawn to the onscreen canvas again but *not* stroked or filled - so it's not actually painted to the canvas and is not visible.
3) Now the path can be tested with isPointInPath()

This works well - though the speed seems more or less the same as using an offscreen canvas that hasn't been added to the DOM.

Anyone have any comments? Particularly with regards to more involved paths?

Comment: It is very unclear what is being asked here. Please add some example code what you try to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your canvas small, like 10x10. It should not affect the path calculation and it takes less memory.

You can test out more complex path performance here:  http://jsperf.com/ispointinpath-boundary-test-speed

Comment: Ok I've done more testing now and looping thru 10,000 rects, drawing them but not actually stroking or filling them takes about 60-70 milliseconds. So for 0-100 I think it will be fine and dandy...